# how to retrieve facebook live video from my own website via facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display facebook live video from a fb page in a website via facebook graph API. I do not understand what the process should be. I have found a [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video) but do not understand the steps to retrieve the video. Could you help me someone what is the easy way as I can retrieve video of a page.

FYI: page is my own and website is mine

Answer (score 0):

The link you have mentioned in your question is the link of an individual video of mentioned page posted on facebook.
If you want to retrieve the **live video** from **facebook graph api** then you have to use this link 
[Live Video using Facebook Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/)

You need to mention `live-video-id` of the live video you want to retrieve from API.
Hope this will help you.